# Swift Compiler Errors caused by Importing Header File in Bridging Header

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, swift, bridging-header

1. My project builds and runs successfully.
2. I create a bridging header, so that I can segue between my Swift and Objective-C views.
3. I import my Objective-C header file in my bridging header.
4. All of a sudden, I have 40 swift compiler errors in my Objective-C header file that I imported. (image attached for details)

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjdPX.png)

Why does this happen, and how can I fix it? My ViewController.h file ran perfectly before I imported it in my bridging header.

Comment: You've given very little information for anyone to base an answer on. 1) the one error in the screenshot is an Objective C error, not Swift. 2) do you import ViewController.h anywhere other than your bridging header? 3) if you keep the bridging header in place and comment out the `#import "ViewController.h"` does any behavior change?

Comment: Hi. Yes, I do #import "ViewController.h" in my header file, and when I comment it out, there are no errors (project builds fine).

Comment: What about question 2?

Comment: Also, please share the contents of ViewController.h

Comment: https://pastebin.com/EVxPw8jj

The errors are occurring on the lines where I am defining constants, saying "Expected ';' at end of declaration list"

Comment: Oh, to question 2, I don't import ViewController.h anywhere else.

Comment: That's what's in your ViewController.h? I would expect to see a `@interface ViewController` in there.  I don't have a computer in front of me, but that doesn't look like valid Objective C. You can't declare structs with default values. Also, if this is the only place the ViewController.h is imported, then its the first time the compiler has tried to compile that file. So that explains why you didn't have any issues before.

Comment: There is @interface ViewController too.

Sorry I was actually wrong earlier. I imported ViewController.h in several other files, not just the bridging header, and it worked fine.

This is code that someone else gave me to work on, not my own lol.

Basically, the problem arose only after I imported it in my bridging header.

Answer (score 0):

To define constants in an Objective C header file, you'll want to do something like this:

```
// header file
FOUNDATION_EXPORT static CGFloat MyNamespaceAlpha;

// implementation file
static CGFloat MyNamespaceAlpha = 0.8f;
```